# add a scheduled task using CMD prompt

Tags: c#, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I have an application that I need to have installed as a scheduled task. I have tried looking around on here and tried a few of the different things but still no go. I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand.

```
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                startInfo.Arguments = "schtasks /create /tn Inc-Andro-BU /tr" +         inbackpath + "/sc minute /mo 10 /ru SYSTEM";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a command window and execute a command  in it you need to add this to the arguments

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C schtasks /create /tn Inc-Andro-BU /tr" +         
                       inbackpath + "/sc minute /mo 10 /ru SYSTEM";
```

The /C flags is needed to pass the argument at the CMD. Otherwise the shell will exit immediately without waiting to execute your command - See CMD.EXE /? on a command window